# python scipy-fsolve doesn`t work. why fsolve return 'None'?

Tags: python, scipy

first, sorry about my poor English skill.

I make BDT-model, but something problem here.

this function is change code for column 4

```py
def f(x):
    a=1 / (1 + f_tree.loc[1, 4] + x)
    b=1 / (1 + f_tree.loc[2, 4] + x)
    c=1 / (1 + f_tree.loc[3, 4] + x)
    d=1 / (1 + f_tree.loc[4, 4] + x)
    e=0.5*(a+b)/ (1 + f_tree.loc[1, 3])
    f=0.5*(b+c)/ (1 + f_tree.loc[2, 3])    
    g=0.5*(c+d)/ (1 + f_tree.loc[3, 3]) 
    h=0.5*(e+f)/ (1 + f_tree.loc[1, 2])
    i=0.5*(f+g)/ (1 + f_tree.loc[2, 2])  
    return -Market_data['PV'][3] + (0.5 * (h+i) / (1+f_tree.loc[1,1]))
x=fsolve(f,0)
x
f_tree.loc[1,4]+=x
f_tree.loc[2,4]+=x
f_tree.loc[3,4]+=x
f_tree.loc[4,4]+=x
f_tree
```

table before

|  | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.05 | 0.065334 | 0.081673 | 0.067493 | 0.074591 |
| 2 | 0.00 | 0.055317 | 0.070603 | 0.055259 | 0.061070 |
| 3 | 0.00 | 0.000000 | 0.061539 | 0.045242 | 0.050000 |
| 4 | 0.00 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.037041 | 0.040937 |
| 5 | 0.00 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.033516 |

table after

|  | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.05 | 0.065334 | 0.081673 | 0.099235 | 0.074591 |
| 2 | 0.00 | 0.055317 | 0.070603 | 0.087001 | 0.061070 |
| 3 | 0.00 | 0.000000 | 0.061539 | 0.076984 | 0.050000 |
| 4 | 0.00 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.068783 | 0.040937 |
| 5 | 0.00 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.033516 |

I try transform to loop, but not working.

this is my code

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import math as m
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
global cal_temp, loop_temp
cal_temp =[]
loop_temp = []
list_temp =[]
final_list = []

# find x
def f2(x):
    temp_val = 0
    temp_val = (1 / (1 + f_tree.loc[1, 2] + x)) + (1 / (1 + f_tree.loc[2, 2] + x))
    return -pv[1] + (0.5 * (temp_val / (1+f_tree.loc[1,1])))
        
def f(x): 
    for j in range(1, n+1):
        i = 1
        while i <= j:
            f_tree_x.loc[i,j] = 1 / (1 + f_tree.loc[i, j] + x)
            i += 1
    list_temp = [value for value in list(np.array(f_tree_x[set_row].tolist())) if value != 0]   
    final = calculate(list_temp, set_row)
    return -pv[(set_row-1)] + (0.5 * sum(map(float, final)) / (1+f_tree.loc[1,1]))

def calculate(take_list, set_row):
    reset = []
    cal_temp = reset
    for row_no in range(set_row-1):
        cal_temp.append(0.5 * (take_list[row_no] + take_list[row_no+1]) / (1 + f_tree.loc[row_no+1, set_row-1]))
    if set_row == 3:
        return cal_temp
    else:
        set_row -= 1
        loop_temp = cal_temp
        calculate(loop_temp, set_row)

# main
n = int(input('typing year(2~10)'))
sr = [0.050, 0.055, 0.060, 0.070, 0.080, 0.090, 0.100, 0.110, 0.120, 0.130, 0.140]
s_fir = [0.050000, 0.060024, 0.070071, 0.142293, 0.130935, 0.151393, 0.171938, 0.192568, 0.213282, 0.234078]
pv= [0.952381, 0.898452, 0.839619, 0.735030, 0.649931, 0.564474, 0.481658, 0.403883, 0.332885, 0.269744]

V = 0.1
u = m.exp(V)
d = 1/u

f_tree = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((n,n)), index=range(1,n+1), columns=range(1,n+1), dtype=float)
f_tree_x = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((n,n)), index=range(1,n+1), columns=range(1,n+1), dtype=float)

for j in range(1, n+1):
    i = 1
    while i <= j:
        f_tree.loc[i,j] = s_fir[0] * (u**(j-i)) * (d**(i-1))
        i += 1
for set_row in range(1, n+1):
    if set_row == 1:
        print(f_tree)
        continue
    if set_row == 2:
        x = fsolve(f2, 0)
        print(x)
        w = 1
        while w <= set_row:
            f_tree.loc[w, set_row] += x
            w += 1
    if set_row >= 3:
        x = fsolve(f, 0)
        print('x')
        print(x)
        # fsolve(f, 0)
        w = 1
        while w <= set_row:
            f_tree.loc[w, set_row] += x
            w += 1
```

loop n=2,3 is fine. but loop n=4 something wrong

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\BDT_model\BDT_3.py", line 102, in <module>
    x = fsolve(f, 0)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py", line 160, in fsolve
    res = _root_hybr(func, x0, args, jac=fprime, **options)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py", line 226, in _root_hybr
    shape, dtype = _check_func('fsolve', 'func', func, x0, args, n, (n,))
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py", line 24, in _check_func
    res = atleast_1d(thefunc(*((x0[:numinputs],) + args)))
  File "d:\BDT_model\BDT_3.py", line 33, in f
    return -pv[(set_row-1)] + (0.5 * sum(map(float, final)) / (1+f_tree.loc[1,1]))
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

plz help

Comment: Based on the error, `calculate` is returning `None` instead of the iterable you're trying to sum. That's what you told it to do. Not sure what else you were expecting to happen.

Comment: still I don`t understand.
if error is entirely in my code,
why 'set_row=3' loop return correct value?

Comment: By the way, why are you tossing the same reference around so many times? `cal_temp = reset` and `loop_temp = cal_temp` make three names point to the same object. You will have an easier time following the code if you get rid of two of them.

Comment: I've updated by answer. I am really not sure what's tripping you up, so I spelled it out

Comment: Also, don't worry about your English. You were able to communicate your issue perfectly well. I would be more concerned with your debugging process than your English :)

Comment: I tried your advise and my code work finally!
Unfortunately return value not corrected but I don`t worry.
I think i can fix it. thanks :)

Comment: And you are right I did same reference unnecessary.
I just wanted make sure list type be empty in recursive function.

Comment: I'm glad it worked out for you. Good luck learning about recursion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to read the error: focus on `not iterable`. Something in the line is attempting to iterate. The only part that makes sense for is `sum(map(float, final))`. So we know that `final` is `None`.

`final` is the return value of `calculate`. Looking at the code, `calculate` does indeed return nothing, rather than the expected iterable.

At one point, `calculate` states

```
if set_row == 3:
    return cal_temp
```

However, the corresponding else recursively calls `calculate(loop_temp, set_row)` and **discards** the return value. You probably want to keep the recursive return value and return it:

```
return calculate(loop_temp, set_row)
```

As usual with these types of problems, the error is entirely in your code, and not in the thoroughly tested and generally well thought-out libraries you are using.